# An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects" and "building Maven Projects"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm getting the below error while importing an maven project from git repositories of STS.

An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
No enum constant org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecyclemapping.model.PluginExecutionAction.items

Please help me to sort this out.[image: Screen shot of the error]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps :

- Removed the project from the workspace.
- Remove .classpath, .project and .settings folder
- Reimport the project.

or

- Run command `mvn eclipse:clean`
- Run command `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `window-> preferences-> Maven -> Installations` and add path to your maven folder (use external maven).
Looks like embedded in eclipse maven is broken

OR

try right click on the project choose `Run as -> maven` build and add Goals: `clean install`

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me after an eclipse automatic update to

> Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)

I had to change the vm running eclipse in eclipse.ini to point to the latest JDK instead of the default JRE.

Comment: I tried changing `-vm` to Azul Zulu JDK 17 but it gives error updating Maven project. I feel like Eclipse sucks now, I'd rather they don't update it coz most Java developers are still using JDK 8 or 11.